# How to implement bump mapping with phong shading

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl

In fragment shader, i have normal vector in view coordinate axis system which is read from 3D model and the bump normal vector which get from bump texture.
If i want to get diffuse factor and specular factor. Shall i just simple plus these two normal or do something else?

Comment: It strongly depends on how you calculate the normal from your bump-texture. When you read depth values along the texture's x and y axis and calculate the derivatives to get the normal, you will have to transform the calculated normal from the tangent space to model space and use it there instead of the object's normal.
When you already calculate the derivatives along the model-space, then you can simply replace the object's normal without any further transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common normal mapping technique for real time usage, requires to calculate in advance the *tangent* and *bi-tangent* vectors per vertex, as addition to the normal vector.

After you have the normal, tangent, binormal vectors, you create a matrix (lets say TBN) to transforms from *view space* to *model's tangent space*.

So (**in the vertex shader**) you transform light vector and eye vectors (required for Lambert diffuse term and Phong reflection)  to tangent space using TBN matrix;

And for example (in the fragment shader) the diffuse term will be D = L dot N; (where L is light position in tangent space and N is the normal vector extracted from the normal map texture).

You can find a detailed tutorial: [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/bumpMapping/).

Comment: It's a bitangent, not a binormal. You can "normal map" in 2D, also, without using a vertex normal, but you'll always need a tangent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is more appropriate to call it bitangent.